# convert WAV to TETRA format

Tags: ffmpeg, speech-recognition, codec, sox

I am trying to convert a wav file into TETRA encoded file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Trunked_Radio). Tetra is used by fire-fighters, it provides a radio-like voice.

I am trying to use the official tetra codec codes available at (https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300300_300399/30039502/01.03.01_60/) and we can easily compile it using the scripts available at https://github.com/sq5bpf/install-tetra-codec.

However, I am not able to figure out how to convert a wav file into tetra codec files using these files. I tried going through the documentation of the compiled files (ccoder, cdecoder, scoder, sdecoder).

I tried the following command -

> tetra/bin/scoder input.wav serial_file synth_file

here serial_file and synth_file are the output files and have following documentation in the scoder.c file:

```
    INPUT   :   - Description : speech file to be analyzed
                - Format : binary file 16 bit-samples
                  240 samples per frame

serial_file :   - Description : serial stream output file 
            - Format : binary file 16 bit-samples
              each 16 bit-sample represents one encoded bit
              138 (= 1 + 137) bits per frame

synth_file  :   - Description : local synthesis output file 
            - Format : binary file 16 bit-samples
```

For an input file of size 13M, I obtained serial_file and synth_file of size 8.0M and 16M. However, I thought since the wav file is getting converted into a walkie-talkie type signal the output file size will be alot smaller.

I want to clarify if:

- I used the correct code to convert an input wav file into a tetra format output file.
- can you please help me understand, what is serial_file and synth_file.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 2):

`synth_file` is an internal computed parameters, you can ignore it.

`serial_file` is actual encoded data, you can use it in sdecoder.

traditionally ETSI code use very unefficent output format where instead of bits they output textual or expanded representation of those bits. I.e. instead of a bit they write a word of 16-bit where all the bits are 0 and the last one has information. They do it to interface with their transmission corruption test tools I presume.

So the actual length of the serial file should be 16 times smaller, so you converted 13Mb to 0.5Mb which is OK.